# xpages dynamically change xpage acl?

Tags: xpages, acl

I have a basic workflow app, and I am having diffiulty.

In the db ACL, I have all the people and groups involved set to Editor.
In an XPage acl, I am trying to enter a computed value for the name. (a field I have called nextApprover, which is stored on the form/document associated with the xpage.

I've tried

```
document1.getItemValue("nextApprover");
```

AND

```
getComponent("nextApprover").getValue();
```

both create a runtime error executing the Javascript computed expression.

All I am trying to do is allow the nextApprover the rights to edit the document when it is in their "box" and allow the rest of the users the ability to read it at that particular time. I've looked around for a while now. 
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't access the datasource `document1` in XPages ACL name calculation because the ACL is first calculated and only later the datasource. That's why you get the JavaScript runtime error.

Here is an alternative to XPages ACL:

Define your datasource `document1` with `action="openDocument"`

```xml
<xp:this.data>
    <xp:dominoDocument
        var="document1"
        action="openDocument"
        ... />
</xp:this.data>
```

That will open the document by default in READ mode.

Then switch in `beforePageLoad` event to EDIT mode with `context.setDocumentMode("edit")` **if** the current user name is in your field `nextApprover`:

```xml
<xp:this.beforePageLoad><![CDATA[#{javascript:
    if (document1.getItemValue("nextApprover").get(0).equals(session.getEffectiveUserName())) {
        context.setDocumentMode("edit")
    }
}]]></xp:this.beforePageLoad>
```

You might have to change the if clause depending on what is really in your field `nextApprover`.

Comment: Another way would be to get the document based on UnID in the URL when computing ACL.

Comment: You would probably need to add code for edit attempt by putting _editDocument_ in URL. Also `setDocumentMode` does not work in `beforePageLoad` at least in 8.5.2 which I've been forced to develop with lately. It works in `afterPageLoad`.

Comment: Thanks Knut. It worked, and I was able to adjust the if clause in the beforePageLoad to determine if the person was a member of a group, etc. Great solution

Answer (score 0):

You get better security by using *Authors*-items on documents instead of XPage ACL.

Try this (if `document1` is datasource name):

```
document1.getValue("nextApprover");
```

If it does not work with this and you still want to use XPage ACL please post your error and XPage XML source for the ACL part.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "Authors-items"?
You mean Authors field on the form associated to the Xpage? I thought that had no impact on the security.

Comment: Items are often created by form fields but not necessarily. Users need to have Author rights to the db. Then authors items determine who can edit documents.

Comment: I am a little lost. I put Authors and Readers fields on my form, but they are not created when I save a doc.

Then, I followed instructions I read to create the items on a postDocumentSave event, but that doesn't work either.

All I am trying to do is allow the nextApprover to have edit access to the document. This is so simple to build with a domino form.

Comment: Use `computeWithForm="onsave"` in your datasource. Then the item type will be Authors when defined on form.

Comment: I appreciate you helping! You say use computeWithForm="onsave" in the datasource. Where exactly do you write that?

Comment: `xp:dominoDocument` tag. Other way to set it: "Run form validation: On document save".